# Gephi: Color Nodes according to a weight in a sparse directed graph

Tags: graph, gephi

I want to use Gephi to visualize a large, sparse graph (it is about 876,000 nodes designed to simulate the "internet" for purposes of testing a page rank algorithm).

Here is the problem: I have calculated the page rank for the nodes in the graph (considering them to be "websites").

---

Now, I need to output the data into a CSV such that Gephi can read it in...and I would like to color the nodes according to a heat map/color map that gives them a color corresponding to their page rank.

So, I would need a graph such that each vertex gets a weight, and then color the graph appropriately.

---

Brand new to Gephi, and I am looking at the [website](https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/csv-format/): it describes how to store edge weights in the adjacency matrix format, but my graph is way to big to store as an adjacency matrix.  If I store it as an **adjacency list,** I don't see a way to store either an edge weight or a node weight.  The format described in the link is:

```
> a;b;c;d
```

Which equates to: node "a" with "a->b","a->c" and "a->d."  However, there does not seem to be a slot in the format for either a node weight, or an edge weight.

---

Is it possible to use Gephi to display a graph that I have described--with the nodes colored according to their weight--and, **if so,** how would I store the graph for Gephi to read?

Comment: Making progress.  Found a plugin for coloring nodes; will come up with a way to convert the weights to a good hex color according to a color map or something, and post a "how to" for doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the page you are referring to might be outdated. On [this page](https://github.com/gephi/gephi/wiki/Import-CSV-Data), they mention two types of CSV: edge vs. node tables.

So, you could generate two distinct CSV files:

- One edge table containing pairs of nodes corresponding to links, maybe weights if you have any.
- One node table containing the list of nodes in your graph, and whatever attributes they have, including your PageRank value.